# forward lookup zone problem

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

In DNS manager i create forward lookup zone. After that I added host A with IP 10.10.101.xxx (this host and DNS have some IP) and name (uses parent domain name i.e. mysite.com). Problem: when type in address bar www.mysite.com I can't see site but can see when type name of my DNS

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use A Record instead of Alias. It is my personal experience that A record which is good and reduce the performance issue. You can check following URL for more information.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html

Gaurav Maniar MCP | MCSE | MCST | MCITP | ITILv3 Certified

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created an A record for the zone (mysite.com) but not an A or CNAME record for www (www.mysite.com).

Comment: I have Alias(CNAME) www